# How to remove text after and before specific words in a string using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string "copy table a (no = 1, name = xyz, city = c0nl ) from 'a.dat';".
In this I want to remove the words within 'copy' and 'from', but need file-name as:
my desirable output is "copy a from a.dat;"

Any help would be great. I want to use regular expression for that.

Comment: what output do you want for "hi copy copybook fromasdf from a.dat" and "hi copybook is copy not from c.dat"  ?

Comment: Still not clear. Is 'a' always part of the file name? Can you have: "copy table foo.... from bar.dat" or is it always "copy table foo ... from foo.dat"?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the regex module [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and the function [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) (replace/substitute) in conjunction with lookahead `(?=from)` and lookbehind `(?<=copy )` - also referred to as [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), in order to remove only the requested part `(.*)` that comes in-between:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'(?<=copy )(.*)(?=from)', '', "copy table values from 'a.dat';")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
copy from 'a.dat';
```

Comment: Now if the string is "copy table abc  from 'abc.dat'\g", how can I drop 'table' but can retain the table name from it. I meant how to achieve the output "copy abc from 'abc.dat'\g". I am confused because table name will be different in all the copy statements.

Comment: @ Basel, I tried but my edited content got rejected. :( so couldn't modify it. for clarity, i would ask the question below again: input string is "copy table a (no = 10, name = "kavya") from a.dat\g" and teh desired output is: "copy a from a.dat\g"

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import re
mystr = "copy table values from 'a.dat';"
print(re.sub('copy.*from', 'copy from', mystr))
```

And you don't worry about spaces, greedyness and all that.

Comment: @ Basel, I tried but my edited content got rejected. :( so couldn't modify it. for clarity, i would ask the question below again: input string is "copy table a (no = 10, name = "kavya") from a.dat\g" and teh desired output is: "copy a from a.dat\g"

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\bcopy\b)[\s\S]*?(?=\s*\bfrom\b)
```

Use `\b` and `lookarounds`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/11

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=\bcopy\b)[\s\S]*?(?=\s*\bfrom\b)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "copy table values from 'a.dat';"
subst = ""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Output: `copy from 'a.dat';`

Comment: @Laawanya the problem with above solution is `asdcopy asd sad fromsds` will be `asd sad` .Do you want this?