# Delete word that follows a specific word

Tags: python, regex

I have e-mails and transcripts in German from conversations with customers. They include personal identifiable information that I need to remove. So it is a data anonymisation task. The text would be *"Hello Mr. Smith"*, *"Dear Mr Smith"*, *"Hello Lisa"* etc. followed by the conversation. I need to keep the conversation for further analysis. Three solutions come to my mind:

**A) compiling a list of names**:
At this stage, I do not know all the names that will be mentioned. I have no access to the CRM database. So compiling a list and adding it to the stopwords corpus will be time-consuming and/or error prone.

**B) Part-of-Speech Tagging (PoS) / Named Entity Recognition (NER)**:
This would also delete product names and places. I need to keep this information. So NER is  unfortunately not an option.

**C) Regular expression (regex)**:
Use RegEx to match the salutation, e.g. "Dear", and delete the subsequent word. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241159/how-to-remove-text-after-and-before-specific-words-in-a-string-using-python-rege) gave me a good starting point, but it assumes that I know the word that follows the name I need to delete which I don't.

```
import re
print re.sub(r'(?<=copy )(.*)(?=from)', '', "copy table values from 'a.dat';")
```

How could I modify the code to delete the word that follows the salutation?

I read up on [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and played around a bit on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/11) but couldn't figure it out.

Also, would I need to tokenize the string first?

A solution with pandas `str.replace` is welcome too.

Comment: Have you considered using PoS/NER to tag the text parts and then removing manually only the first (or 2+ sequential) part recognized as a name?

Comment: You say _" delete the subsequent word"_ but in your case you (may) have more _"Hello Mr. Smith"_

Comment: @hedfol         So you mean to use a lookaround to select the salutation part, put it in a seperate string variable, do NER, then put it together again?

Comment: @cards            Depends on how *salutation* is defined. In my case it would be *Sehr geehrter Herr* // *Sehr geehrte Frau* // *Guten Tag Frau* etc. ;-)  I reckon that even if I have *Sehr geehrte Frau Müller-Kuhn* the double-barrelled name would this be considered one word. Though this doesn't hold when there is no hyphen in between. So you are right! Thanks.

Comment: what about counting the amount of white spaces contained in the 1st line?

Comment: Good idea - how would you implement it?  On a side note, I am just ignoring the fact that we all make typos and may type more than one white space in between words. I think I'll have to aim for a 80/20 solution

Comment: @Simone Even without lookaround - the easiest would be to just tag the first N chars (i.e., 250) that a simple model can handle, find the name words and replace them with "" in the original text.

Comment: Maybe `re.sub(r'\bDear(?: +[A-Z]\w*\.?)+', '', text)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Thanks a lot. Worked for if the surname is *Smith* but not if it is *Smith-Walker*. However, it works for *Smith Walker*. I guess I can just remove hyphens beforehand.

Comment: Wait, I will adjust and post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2a
You could approach this by setting up lists of salutations and of honorifics (Mr, Mrs, Dr etc), and if any word in your data matched one of these working through the first few words you could remove it. This approach makes it easy to quickly add new salutations and honorifics as you spot them in the transcripts.

This first piece of code is an improvement on my earlier answer (which is listed at the end). @Simone added the requirement that the salutation could be a pair of words (Good morning rather than just Hello - for example). The new code copes with this, and also works for double names (such as John Doe as well as just John). It also works with a fairly wide range of less conventional ways of addressing someone (and is not fooled by capitalisation or the lack of it) which might appear in an email or a transcript, as hopefully the example text in the code shows. However, although it is more bullet-proof than the first version, it is not perfect - as you might expect from code that is trying to second-guess human responses.

```
import re

text = ["Dear  mrs chan Blah blah blah", "Dear fred smith, How are  you?",
        "greetings ms duncan-jones, what Gives?", " My   Dear   Lisa , this is cool.",
        "Hello Dr Foster It's good, to hear, from you.", "Meera Whatcha thinkin?",
        "Good morning Ms Daisy Martin, Hope you are keeping well.",
        "Hi there seema hows things?", "Jaz Yes ok", "OK raffi you may be right"]

salutations_1 = ["dear", "dearest", "hello", "hi", "hiya", "greetings", "salutations", "ok", "good", "my"]
salutations_2 = ["morning", "day", "afternoon", "evening", "there", "dear", "dearest"]
honorifics = ["mr", "mrs", "dr", 'ms', "sir", "master"]

for line in text:
    line = line.replace(',', ' #', 1)   # Mark the position of the first comma
    line = line.strip()
    words = re.split(r"[\s]+", line)
    try:
        # First salutation word
        if words[0].lower() in salutations_1:
            words = words[1:]
            # Second salutation word
            if words[0].lower() in salutations_2:
                words = words[1:]
        # Honorifics
        if words[0].lower() in honorifics:
            words = words[1:]
        # Remove 1st name (eg John)
        words = words[1:]
        # Remove comma marker if present
        if words[0] == '#':
            words = words[1:]
        # Remove possible second name (eg Doe) and comma marker
        if words[1] == '#':
            words = words[2:]
        joined = ' '.join(words)
        finished = joined.replace(' #', ',')   # Restore any unused comma

        print(finished)
    except:
        print("**Line too short**")
```

This gives:

```
Blah blah blah
How are you?
what Gives?
this is cool.
It's good, to hear, from you.
Whatcha thinkin?
Hope you are keeping well.
hows things?
Yes ok
you may be right
```

It has removed all the salutations, honorifics and names without losing any of the accompanying text.

This is the earlier version of the code, left here for completeness.

```
import re

text = ["Dear mrs smith Blah", "Dear fred, how are  you. It is a while, since etc",
        " Dear Lisa, this is great", "Hello Dr Foster, It's good to hear from you."]

salutations = ["dear", "hello", "hi"]

honorifics = ["mr", "mrs", "dr"]

for line in text:
    line = line.strip()
    words = re.split(r"[\s]+", line)
    #print(words)
    for word in words:
        if word.lower() in salutations:
            words.remove(word)
    for word in words:
        if word.lower() in honorifics:
            words.remove(word)
    del words[0]   # Remove the name

    print(' '.join(words))
```

From the data above, this prints out:

```
Blah
how are you. It is a while, since etc
this is great
It's good to hear from you.
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great (also in German ;-) ). When working with transcripts it is likely that the customer name appears through-out the transcript. It is good call centre practice to call the customer by name several times during the phone conversation. Will also extend loop with a ```closing``` variable to remove the name of the call centre agent.

Comment: Cool. If there is a liklihood of a name appearing more than once in a transcript, you could pick it up before you delete it with del words[0] part of the code, and then specifically remove it from the rest of the sequence. This would be useful because any salutation and honorific markers might not always accompany the name in the later parts of the transcript.

Comment: yes - did exactly that. Adapted the script so that it collects the deleted names so I can build a dictionary later on. At the moment I am working on the first data batch. Though haven't managed to do the closing bit just yet. Isn't as straight forward as I thought

Comment: What does ```word.strip() == '':``` do?

Comment: Good question :) In earlier testing I had the odd instance where the resultant strings contained an empty word, and that line got rid of it. But with the current code it seems to be completely redundant! I will edit it out.

Comment: It doesn't remove the names when the salutations is more than one word, e.g. *good morning*. It removes *morning*. So I tried to include just *morning* in the salutation variable. Curious thing, it doesn't work.

Comment: To catch this you would need to add the word 'good' to the salutations, and add a third tier of word checks between the other two:
     for word in words:
        if word.lower() in third_check:
            words.remove(word)
where third_check was a list like ['morning'. 'evening'] etc

Comment: O.k. thanks! Will look into it. Also exploring the POS tagging solution as previously suggested. People use more salutation variants that I previously imagined. These would need to be adjusted for spelling mistakes. So it gets complex fairly quickly.

Comment: @Lex_xp         added the third tier in-between tier 1 and 2. It did not remove the name. Also put the third underneath the 1st tier. No success. Instead I applied the function twice. That did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Simone I have edited my answer to accommodate the two-word greeting request, and more besides.

Comment: Oh wow - thanks a lot Lee-xp. Will try to integrate it into the function I have written.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
re.sub(r'''\b(?:Dear|H(?:ello|i))(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]\w*(?:[’'-]\w+)*\.?)+''', '', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rWQsfC/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:Dear|H(?:ello|i))` - Dear`,` Hello`or`Hi`
- `(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]\w*(?:[’'-]\w+)*\.?)+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `[^\S\r\n]+` - one or more whitespaces other than CR and LF
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `\w*` - any zero or more letters/digits/connector punctuation (="word") chars
  - `(?:[’'-]\w+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a `’`, `'` or `-` and then one or more word chars
  - `\.?` - an optional `.` char.

Comment: Oh wow - thanks so much! I am sure this will be super useful to others as well! If you could just add a parenthesis. It throws a syntax error that a parenthesis is missing.

Comment: @Simone Sorry, the single apostrophe `'` symbol needed escaping, but a `'''` string literal delimiter would be safer.

Comment: Escaping worked ```re.sub(r'\b(?:Dear|H(?:ello|i))(?:[^\S\r\n]+[A-Z]\w*(?:[\’\'-]\w+)*\.?)+', '', text)
```  Thanks